# Free SSL CERTS in GCE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I subscribed to Google cloud computing engine, I just want to ask is there free SSL CERT ? because I want my website to run https .

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can just generate a self-signed certificate, here is how: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10176685/6154099

Comment: You can also use https://letsencrypt.org/ which is a free certificate authority you can use for your website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

letsencrypt and renew it every 3 months or setup script for automatic renewal, or just pay a few dollars to get proper SSL. I found one only $3.88/year, just try to google for it.